# Replace atsam3x with atsam

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I just noticed that we have no tag for the ATSAM family of ARM microcontrollers from Microchip (former Atmel). Questions about these microcontrollers are somewhat common.

I noticed that we do have a sub-family tag [atsam3x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atsam3x), which is about a specific sub category. These family-specific tags are mildly useful and tend to be spammy (as we can see from STM32 tags). The most important part is to know the family (ATSAM) and the core (Cortex M etc). The sub family names (3x in this case) is just about available peripherals and memory.

I propose that we rename [atsam3x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atsam3x) to [atsam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atsam). Since all [atsam3x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atsam3x) are also [atsam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atsam), it doesn't affect existing posts. I can write a tag wiki with usage guidance once this is fixed.